# Java Issues with Implements a new JPanel with AVL tree

Tags: java, swing

So I am creating an AVL tree and need to repaint the tree onto the `JFrame` I have created. This issue is I can't get the graphics function onto the frame. I managed to get it to create it in a new Frame that I create. I've tried making a `JLabel`, `Textfield`, etc. I can't seem to figure this out. I'd be really grateful if someone could explain to me how to get this onto the same frame and repaint everytime a new number is inserted or removed. Issue starts at about 216 down. I add components and then create the new Frame to paint in the action listener section

```
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.Shape;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.border.Border;



class AVLTree {

    class Node {
        int N;
        int height = 0;
        Node parent = null, left = null, right = null;

        Node(int n, int h, Node P) {
            N = n;
            height = h;
            parent = P;
        }
    }

    Node root = null;

    void insert(int N, Node R) {
        if (root == null)
            root = new Node(N, 1, null);
        else {
            if (N <= R.N) {
                if (R.left == null) {
                    R.left = new Node(N, 1, R);
                    dobalance(R.left);
                } else
                    insert(N, R.left);
            } else {
                if (R.right == null) {
                    R.right = new Node(N, 1, R);
                    dobalance(R.right);
                } else
                    insert(N, R.right);
            }
        }
    }

    void remove(Node x) {
        Node y, z = null;
        if (x.left == null || x.right == null) // atleast one child
            y = x;
        else { // finding successor
            Node temp = x;
            for (y = temp.parent; y != null && temp == y.right; y = y.parent) {
                temp = y;
            }
        } // both child or no child

        // y has atmost one child
        if (y.left != null)
            z = y.left;
        else
            z = y.right;

        if (z != null)
            z.parent = y.parent;

        if (y.parent == null) // z was is root
            root = z;
        else { // removing y
            if (y == y.parent.left) // y was in left
                y.parent.left = z;
            else
                y.parent.right = z; // y was in right
        }
        x.N = y.N; // copying y to x
        y.height = 0;

        do {
            y = dobalance(y);
        } while (y != null); // balancing till root
    }

    /************
     * Reforming tree after deletion or insertion operation
     ***********/
    Node dobalance(Node x) {
        int h1 = 0, h2 = 0; // here h1 height of x,h2 height of x`s sibling
        Node n1 = null, rent = null;
        Node y = x, z;
        while (y.parent != null) {
            if (y.parent.left == y)
                n1 = y.parent.right;
            else if (y.parent.right == y)
                n1 = y.parent.left;
            h1 = y.height;
            if (n1 == null)
                h2 = 0;
            else
                h2 = n1.height;
            if (Math.abs(h2 - h1) > 1)
                break;
            y.parent.height = 1 + Math.max(h1, h2);
            y = y.parent;
        }

        if (y.parent == null)
            return null;

        z = y.parent;
        rent = z;
        /*
         * linking z to y and y to x. such that y and x has maximum height among
         * sibling respectively
         */
        h1 = (z.left == null) ? 0 : z.left.height;
        h2 = (z.right == null) ? 0 : z.right.height;
        if (h1 < h2)
            y = z.right;
        else
            y = z.left;

        h1 = (y.left == null) ? 0 : y.left.height;
        h2 = (y.right == null) ? 0 : y.right.height;
        if (h1 < h2)
            x = y.right;
        else
            x = y.left;

        y.parent = z;
        x.parent = y;

        // finding the type of rotation needed to balance tree
        if (z.left == y) {
            if (y.left == x)
                Rrotation(y, z); // single left rotation
            else {
                Lrotation(x, y); // double left rotation
                x.height++;
                Rrotation(x, z);
            }
        } else {
            if (y.right == x) {
                Lrotation(y, z); // single right rotation
            } else {
                Rrotation(x, y); // double right rotation
                x.height++;
                Lrotation(x, z);
            }
        }

        return rent;
    }

    /*************
     * Right rotation which take two node and rotate second as first take center
     ***********/
    void Rrotation(Node y, Node z) {
        // linking y with original parent of z
        y.parent = z.parent;
        if (y.parent == null)
            root = y;
        else if (y.parent.left == z)
            y.parent.left = y;
        else
            y.parent.right = y;

        // rotation b/w y n z
        z.left = y.right;
        if (z.left != null)
            z.left.parent = z;
        y.right = z;
        z.parent = y;
        z.height--;
    }

    /*************
     * Left rotation which take two node and rotate second as first take center
     ***********/
    void Lrotation(Node y, Node z) {
        // linking y with original parent of z
        y.parent = z.parent;
        if (z.parent == null)
            root = y;
        else if (z.parent.left == z)
            y.parent.left = y;
        else
            y.parent.right = y;

        // rotation b/w x n y
        z.right = y.left;
        if (z.right != null)
            z.right.parent = z;
        y.left = z;
        z.parent = y;
        z.height--;
    }

    /************
     * To Search node from tree
     **********/
    Node search(int N, Node r) {
        if (r == null)
            return null;
        if (N == r.N)
            return r;
        else if (N < r.N)
            return search(N, r.left);
        else
            return search(N, r.right);
    }

    static AVLTree AVL;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AVL = new AVLTree();
        new Main();
    }

    /**** Classes for grahpics and GUI ***/
    static class Main extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
        /**
         * 
         */


        public Main() {
            super("Avl");
            this.setSize(800, 600);
            this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            this.setTitle("AVL Tree");
            setLayout(new BoxLayout(getContentPane(), BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

            JPanel titlePanel = new JPanel();
            titlePanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
            JLabel title = new JLabel("<HTML> <H1> AVL Tree Editor </H1> </HTML>");
            titlePanel.add(title);

            JPanel inputPanel = new JPanel();
            inputPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(inputPanel, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));


            JLabel insertLabel = new JLabel("Insert");
            insertInput = new JTextField("", 30);
            insertInput.setActionCommand("Insert");
            JPanel insertPanel = new JPanel();
            insertPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
            insertPanel.add(insertLabel);
            insertPanel.add(insertInput);

            JLabel removeLabel = new JLabel("Remove");
            removeInput = new JTextField("", 30);
            removeInput.setActionCommand("Remove");
            JPanel removePanel = new JPanel();
            removePanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
            removePanel.add(removeLabel);
            removePanel.add(removeInput);

            inputPanel.add(insertPanel);
            inputPanel.add(removePanel);




            add(titlePanel);
            add(inputPanel);


            insertInput.addActionListener(this);
            removeInput.addActionListener(this);





            this.setVisible(true);
        }



        JPanel panel1;
        private JButton button0, button1, button2, button3;
        private JTextField insertInput, removeInput;
        private String display = "";

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String com = e.getActionCommand();

            if (com.equals("Insert")) {
                String s = insertInput.getText();
                insertInput.setText("");
                int i = Integer.parseInt(s);
                AVL.insert(i, AVL.root);
            } else if (com.equals("Remove")) {
                String s = removeInput.getText();
                removeInput.setText("");
                int i = Integer.parseInt(s);
                Node temp = AVL.search(i, AVL.root);
                if (temp == null)
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Not Found");
                else {
                    AVL.remove(temp);
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Removed");
                }
            }
            JFrame f = new JFrame("AVL Tree");
            f.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
                public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {}
            });

            Drawtree applet = new Drawtree();
            f.getContentPane().add("Center", applet);
            Toolkit tk = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
            int xSize = ((int) tk.getScreenSize().getWidth() / 2);
            applet.init(AVL.root, xSize - 50);
            f.pack();
            f.setSize(new Dimension(xSize, 500));
            f.setVisible(true);

        }
    }

    /************
     * Drawing Tree using 2d graphics from java class
     ******************/
    static class Drawtree extends JComponent {
        /**
         * 
         */
        final Color bg = Color.white;
        final Color fg = Color.black;
        final Color red = Color.red;
        final Color white = Color.white;
        final BasicStroke stroke = new BasicStroke(2.0 f);
        final BasicStroke wideStroke = new BasicStroke(8.0 f);

        Dimension totalSize;
        int height, width;
        Node r = null;

        public void init(Node N, int x) {
            // Initialize drawing colors
            setBackground(bg);
            setForeground(fg);
            r = N;
            width = x;
        }

        Graphics2D g2;

        public void paint(Graphics g) {
            g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
            g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
            getSize();
            inorder(r, 0, width, 80);
        }

        public void draw(int x1, int x2, int y, String n, int d) {
            g2.setStroke(stroke);

            g2.setPaint(Color.black);
            int x = (x1 + x2) / 2;
            if (d == 1)
                g2.draw(new Line2D.Double(x2, y - 30, x + 15, y));
            else if (d == 2)
                g2.draw(new Line2D.Double(x + 15, y, x1 + 30, y - 30));
            g2.setPaint(Color.blue);
            Shape circle = new Ellipse2D.Double((x1 + x2) / 2, y, 30, 30);
            g2.draw(circle);
            g2.fill(circle);
            g2.setPaint(Color.white);
            g2.drawString(n, x + 10, y + 18);
        }

        int x1 = 500, y1 = 30;

        void inorder(Node r, int x1, int x2, int y) {
            if (r == null)
                return;

            inorder(r.left, x1, (x1 + x2) / 2, y + 40);
            if (r.parent == null)
                draw(x1, x2, y, r.N + "", 0);
            else {
                if (r.parent.N < r.N)
                    draw(x1, x2, y, r.N + "", 2);
                else
                    draw(x1, x2, y, r.N + "", 1);
            }
            inorder(r.right, (x1 + x2) / 2, x2, y + 40);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Too many code to read. Can you make your problem more specific?

Answer (score 0):

What you could try is define a Drawtree object at the class level, then instantiate and add it to the main JFrame when you are setting up the screen. Then inside your actionPerformed() method, remove the bit to do with the second JFrame, then simply do a repaint at the end.

For example:

```
Drawtree applet;

public Main() {
    ...
    applet = new Drawtree();
    add(applet);
    ...
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    ...
    Toolkit tk = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
    int xSize = ((int) tk.getScreenSize().getWidth() / 2);
    applet.init(AVL.root, xSize - 50);
    repaint();
}
```